# discord.js Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning : TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I made an auto role code for my bot recently, which reads the status of every user and gives them a role if they have our server vanity invite link in their status. The code works perfectly, the bot adds the role, and removes it, but the problem here is it loops through an error without crashing the bot :

```
(node:38) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null
(node:38) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 345)
```

I'm pretty sure it's because the bot isn't able to read the status of such users who are offline and don't have a status. I'd be thankful for a help since I couldn't figure out the fix to this.
This is my code :

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {

    const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get("832132526302035992");
    const member = newPresence.member
    const activities = member.user.presence.activities[0];
  
    if (activities && (activities.state.includes( ".gg/moonxile" ) || activities.state.includes("discord.gg/moonxile" ))) {
      return newPresence.member.roles.add(role)
      .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      return;
      })

    } else {
    if(member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {
      newPresence.member.roles.remove(role)
      .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      return;

      })
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With some people when they change from exist state to none it will not having data so the checking should be

```js
    if (activities &&  activities.state && (activities.state.includes( ".gg/moonxile" ) || activities.state.includes("discord.gg/moonxile" ))) {
      return newPresence.member.roles.add(role)
      .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      return;
      })

    }
```

Comment: The bot removes the role when the user goes offline, and adds it back when he/she comes back online

Comment: [here](https://pastebin.com/QsYCNyp6) is what the console shows

Comment: That is another problem errors. Can you give more information have did you get that errors

Comment: The bot removes the role when the user goes offline, and adds it back when he/she comes back online –> You have to check if user status is not offline and that change their state if you want to prevent this behaviour

Comment: oh ok lemme do that

Comment: Ok new topic if you need help

Comment: how do i make it so that the bot ignores offline users, and only add / remove roles when they're online

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232692/discussion-between-darshan-b-and-hellcatvn).

Answer (score 0):

Check for `activities` first, then check for `activities.state` and finally include `.include()`

Comment: oh ok let me try that

Comment: welp, the console is flooded with this :
`(node:174) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
(node:174) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag --unhandled-rejections=strict (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 5)`

Comment: Oh well. Updated.

Comment: welp I tried that and i got [this error](https://pastebin.com/5UwpGRc5)